# arrange multiple column value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I tried to arrange the following table using the following command. The output is  ordered ascendingly. How to get the desired output?

```
SELECT x.TheColumn
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT Title as TheColumn, Title, 1 AS MyOrder
FROM Fables

UNION

SELECT TitleDisplay as TheColumn, Title, 2 AS MyOrder
FROM Fables
WHERE TitleDisplay IS NOT NULL
) x
ORDER BY x.Title, x.MyOrder, x.TheColumn;
```

Table:

### [image: Table Fables]

Output:

### [image: output]

Need output like

```
the wolf
chapter1.1
chapter1.2
the tortoise
chapter2.1
the crab
chapter3.1
the frog
chapter4.1
```

Comment: Why do you need that display?

Comment: While it is probably possible to get this result directly from the database, this kind of thing usually belongs in the presentation layer of a program. What RDBMS are you working with?

Comment: @strawberry- it is part of a story app display in a table view

Comment: @Zohar - it is a simple sqlite used for mobile app

Comment: Try using number instead of title as the second column in your query.

Comment: @Zohar- that separates the Titledisplay from Title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to employ `Number` column in your query in order to get the correct order:

```
SELECT x.TheColumn
FROM
(
   SELECT Title as TheColumn, MIN(Number) AS Number, 1 AS MyOrder
   FROM Fables
   GROUP BY Title

   UNION

   SELECT TitleDisplay as TheColumn, Number, 2 AS MyOrder
   FROM Fables
   WHERE TitleDisplay IS NOT NULL
) x
ORDER BY x.Number, x.MyOrder, x.TheColumn;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/87b9f/3)

Things become a bit more complicated if `TitleDisplay` is unordered within each `Title` partition:

```
SELECT x.TheColumn
FROM
(
   SELECT Title as TheColumn, MIN(Number) AS Number, 1 AS MyOrder
   FROM Fables
   GROUP BY Title

   UNION

   SELECT TitleDisplay as TheColumn,        
         (SELECT MIN(NUMBER)
          FROM Fables
          WHERE Title = f.Title) AS Number,
          2 AS MyOrder
   FROM Fables AS f
   WHERE TitleDisplay IS NOT NULL  
) x
ORDER BY x.Number, x.MyOrder, x.TheColumn;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/77ab3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT x.TheColumn
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT Title as TheColumn, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Fables B WHERE B.Title >= A.Title) As RowNumberByTitle, 
       1 AS MyOrder
FROM Fables A

UNION

SELECT TitleDisplay as TheColumn, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Fables B WHERE B.Title >= A.Title) As RowNumberByTitle, 
       2 AS MyOrder
FROM Fables A
WHERE TitleDisplay IS NOT NULL
) x

ORDER BY x.RowNumberByTitle, x.MyOrder, x.TheColumn;
```

Basically, the sub query is imitating Sql Server's [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function with a Partition by clause.

Comment: Sorry to say the output is in descending order (or vice verse of achieved before)

Comment: Giorgos got it right, I think, so my first hunch was not far from the solution after all...